# What is "valid" meaning in PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

[PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials method creates the connection to the server and validates the specified credentials if the connection is successful.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

What does "valid" mean here? Does it mean that whent the user is valid all are of this list are `true` at the same time:

- password not expired,
- account not locked
- etc.

or it simply means that there is some record (even for the user account that is "disabled") for given "userName" and "password"?

Answer (score 0):

The [source code for the .NET Core implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0eb5e7451028e9374b8bb03972aa945c128193e1/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs#L505) is available to view. It should be much the same as the full .NET Framework implementation.

`ValidateCredentials` performs an LDAP Bind to the domain. Essentially, it performs a login on a domain controller. So, yes, "valid" means that the password is not expired, the account is not locked, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if the "Last login" attribute(if there is such in AD) for that credential changes on this operation.

Comment: Yes, I would expect it to change. But note that the last login attribute is not replicated, so it only changes on the domain controller where the login was performed.

Comment: Thank you. I assume it only changes on successful login. But who knows.. :)

Comment: Yes. The last failed login would change if it wasn't successful.